# Python RegEx Filter Initial Number

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I was able to find all the credit card numbers in the text document, however, I want to filter it so that it only prints the cards that begin with either a '4' or '5'. I tried the ^ notation to no avail. Where am I going wrong?

```
#credit cards - visa starts with '4' and mastercard starts with '5'
re.findall(r'(?:[0-9]{4}-){3}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16}|(?:[0-9]{4}\s? ){3}[0-9]{4}|[0-9]{16}', reg)

#reg contains the following cc numbers
['4916 0636 4700 5548',
 '4556-0775-2249-5041',
 '5119 0966 3584 2334',
 '5108-5708-8343-5937',
 '1234 2345 3456 4567',
 '2132-3523-3211-3356',
 '5118-3323-1315-9900']
```

Comment: How about simply using `x.startswith('4') or x.startswith('5')`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 `startswith()` also accepts a tuple of strings, would come down to: `x.startswith(('4', '5'))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import re
cards = ['4916 0636 4700 5548',
 '4556-0775-2249-5041',
 '5119 0966 3584 2334',
 '5108-5708-8343-5937',
 '1234 2345 3456 4567',
 '2132-3523-3211-3356',
 '5118-3323-1315-9900']
new_cards = [card for card in cards if re.findall('^5|^4', card)]
```

Output:

```
['4916 0636 4700 5548', '4556-0775-2249-5041', '5119 0966 3584 2334', '5108-5708-8343-5937', '5118-3323-1315-9900']
```

Answer (score 1):

A *non-regex solution* may involve using [`str.startswith()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith) and providing a tuple of possible beginning of the string:

> `str.startswith(prefix[, start[, end]])`
>
> Return `True` if string starts with the prefix, otherwise return `False`. `prefix` can also be a tuple of prefixes to look for.

```
In [1]: cards = ['4916 0636 4700 5548',
   ...:  '4556-0775-2249-5041',
   ...:  '5119 0966 3584 2334',
   ...:  '5108-5708-8343-5937',
   ...:  '1234 2345 3456 4567',
   ...:  '2132-3523-3211-3356',
   ...:  '5118-3323-1315-9900']

In [2]: [card for card in cards if card.startswith(('4', '5'))]
Out[2]: 
['4916 0636 4700 5548',
 '4556-0775-2249-5041',
 '5119 0966 3584 2334',
 '5108-5708-8343-5937',
 '5118-3323-1315-9900']
```